# ¿Por qué no me deja validar que las variables no permitan valores negativos o ceros?

Tags: c#

Mi problema es que el ejercicio me pide: validar que las variables no permitan
valores negativos o ceros; esto lo debe hacer en los métodos accesores o propiedades.

Y ese es el problema por que no lo hace y quiero que me muestre el mensaje que me diga no se puede tener un valor negativo

```
namespace Ejercicio8
{
    class Trapecio
    {
      public  double area = 0, bm = 0, bme = 0, h = 0;

        public double Calculo()
        {
            area = (bm + bme) * h / 2;
            return area;
        }

        public double Area
        {
            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    area = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No se puede tener un valor negativo.");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return area;
            }
        }
        public double Bm
        {
            get
            {
                return bm;
            }
            set
            {
                if (bm >= 0)
                {
                    value = bm;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error"+ Bm);
                }
            }
        }
        public double Bme
        {
            get
            {
                return bme;
            }
            set
            {
                if (bme >= 0)
                {
                    value = bme;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error"+ Bme);
                }
            }
        }
        public double H
        {
            get
            {
                return h;
            }
            set
            {
                if (h >= 0)
                {
                    value = h;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error"+H);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Trapecio t = new Trapecio();
                Console.WriteLine("===Encontrar el area de un trapecio====");

                Console.WriteLine("Digite la base mayor del trapecio:");
                t.bm = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la base menor del trapecio:");
                t.bme = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Digite la altura del trapecio: ");
                t.h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                t.Calculo();

                Console.WriteLine("====== RESULTADOS =======");
                Console.WriteLine("La base mayor ingresada es de:" + t.Bm);
                Console.WriteLine("La base menor ingresada es de:" + t.Bme);
                Console.WriteLine("La altura ingresada es de: " + t.H);
                Console.WriteLine("El area del trapecio es de:" + t.Area);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solamente estas controlando el ingreso en area. En los otros casos tus set estan mal, es asi lo que te esta pasando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las respuestas de LPZadkiel y Martin son complementarias. La solución es invertir la validación en la declaración del setter y getter, y cambiar el llamado de la variable en el método `main`. Así:

```
namespace Ejercicio8
{
    class Trapecio
    {
        // Cambio de public por private
        private double area = 0, bm = 0, bme = 0, h = 0;

        public double Calculo()
        {
            area = (bm + bme) * h / 2;
            return area;
        }

        public double Area
        {
            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    area = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No se puede tener un valor negativo.");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return area;
            }
        }
        public double Bm
        {
            get
            {
                return bm;
            }
            set
            {
                // Cambio de variable a validar
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    bm = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error"+ Bm);
                }
            }
        }
        public double Bme
        {
            get
            {
                return bme;
            }
            set
            {
                // Cambio de variable a validar
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    bme = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error"+ Bme);
                }
            }
        }
        public double H
        {
            get
            {
                return h;
            }
            set
            {
                // Cambio de variable a validar
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    h = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error"+H);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Trapecio t = new Trapecio();
            Console.WriteLine("===Encontrar el area de un trapecio====");

            Console.WriteLine("Digite la base mayor del trapecio:");
            // Cambio de variable de llamado
            t.Bm = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la base menor del trapecio:");
            // Cambio de variable de llamado
            t.Bme = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Digite la altura del trapecio: ");
            // Cambio de variable de llamado
            t.H = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            t.Calculo();

            Console.WriteLine("====== RESULTADOS =======");
            Console.WriteLine("La base mayor ingresada es de:" + t.Bm);
            Console.WriteLine("La base menor ingresada es de:" + t.Bme);
            Console.WriteLine("La altura ingresada es de: " + t.H);
            Console.WriteLine("El area del trapecio es de:" + t.Area);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay que aclarar algo. Ninguna de las respuestas soluciona el real problema, ya que si se ingresa un valor invalido el programa escribe un error en la consola, pero sigue como si nada.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Sin embargo, el post dice `quiero que me muestre el mensaje que me diga no se puede tener un valor negativo`

Answer (score 2):

lo estas haciendo al revés, cuando haces un set al no definir el nombre del parámetro por defecto este se llama `value` pero lo que tu haces es asignar a ese el valor que ya estaba (que por defecto es 0). Dicho esto tu propiedad `area` es el único que esta bien, el resto están mal

```
public double Bm
        {
            get
            {
                return bm;
            }
            set
            {
                // esto es lo que tu tenías
                //if (bm >= 0)
                //{
                //    value = bm;
                //}
                if (value >= 0) 
                {
                    bm = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error"+ /*Bm*/value);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

En la clase Trapecio tienes que cambiar la siguiente linea

```
public double area = 0, bm = 0, bme = 0, h = 0;
```

por

```
public double area, bm, bme, h;
```

o

```
private double area, bm, bme, h;
```

porque no es necesario inicializar las variables de las clases. Ademas en los set tienes >= 0 tienes que cambairlo por > 0.
Ademas los nombres de los set en la clase Program tienen que ser en mayuscula

Ejemplo:

```
t.Bm = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Siempre es mejor inicializar, y eso no genera ningun error. El error de >= es correcto, pero el problema me parece que viene por otro lado. No entendi lo de las mayusculas que decis.

Comment: El tiene el código t.bm = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); pero la funcion se llama Bm. Esto puede generar error pórque C# es case sensitive

Comment: Perfecto, explicalo un poco mejor en la respuesta la proxima ;)

Comment: Gracias, lo tomare en cuenta.